# Linux runtime linker error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, poco

I'm working though the [First Steps](http://pocoproject.org/wiki/index.php/FirstStepsLinux) tutorial on the POCO Project site, and I've successfully built the library (Debian Linux, 2.6.26, gcc 4.3.2) under my home directory

```
~/Development/POCO
```

with the shared libraries located in

```
~/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64/lib
```

**My problem is that any application I build that depends on these libraries can only be run from the shared library directory.**

```
~/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64$ ldd ~/Development/Cloud/DateTimeSample/bin/Linux/x86_64/DateTime
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe69fe000)
        libPocoFoundation.so.6 (0x00007fa8de44f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa8de233000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa8de02f000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa8dde26000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa8ddb1a000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa8dd897000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa8dd680000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa8dd32d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa8de7e0000)
```

And running DateTime from this directory would work as you would expect. However

```
~/Development/Cloud/DateTimeSample/bin/Linux/x86_64$ ldd DateTime
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff24dfe000)
        libPocoFoundation.so.6 => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffc1c7dd000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffc1c5d9000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffc1c3d0000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffc1c0c4000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffc1be41000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffc1bc2a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffc1b8d7000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffc1c9f9000)
```

so running the executable from any other directory results in

```
error while loading shared libraries: libPocoFoundation.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the output from the make process, the directory is correctly specified

```
g++ [blah] -L/home/npalko/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64 
           -lPocoFoundation
```

I've tried setting

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to

```
/home/npalko/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64
```

, but it has not changed anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah, my problem was that I had set LD_LIBRARY_PATH incorrectly. More of a misunderstanding of Bash than anything else. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to have to deal with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, you can add the linker `-rpath` option to the gcc command line. In your case, this would be:

```
gcc ... -Wl,-rpath=/home/npalko/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64
```

This effectively hardcodes that path in the executable, so it may or may not be suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This fails?

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/npalko/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64 ~/Development/Cloud/DateTimeSample/bin/Linux/x86_64/DateTime
```

Just thought you may not be setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly

And this?

```
ls -alh /home/npalko/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64/libPocoFoundation.so
```

If both fail I can't see a reason.

Comment: Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is in general a bad idea: your binary works for you (sometimes) but not for your friend, or you forget to set it before your presentation. Using -rpath at static link time is usually a much better option.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify to the linker the path of your library

```
g++ [blah] -Wl,-rpath=/home/npalko/Development/POCO/lib/Linux/x86_64
```

**-Wl** means your pass an option to the linker

**-rpath** is the linker option

*Add    a  directory to the runtime library search path.  This is used
when linking an ELF executable with shared  objects.   All  -rpath
arguments  are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which
uses them to locate shared objects at runtime.  The -rpath  option
is  also  used  when  locating  shared  objects which are needed by
shared objects explicitly included in the link;*

Comment: +1.  Was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to link using -R when gcc was calling the linker.  Your answer was much better google bait than the accepted answer.  Thanks!